# Pairs-type matrix of plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, correlation, ggpairs

I am working on a dataset with a single regressor, and `d` many response variables. While working with that, I have encountered a dataframe of correlations, with `1 + dC2 = 1 + d(d-1)/2` which exactly looks like the ones that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76685236/12036804). I'm inserting an example of such a dataframe:

```
   X      r_{1,2}     r_{1,3}      r_{1,4}      r_{1,5}      r_{2,3}      r_{2,4}      r_{.,.}
1 21    0.6002993    0.923644    0.8184414    0.3721132    0.9337539    0.6569090    .........
2 22    0.6498641    0.358339    0.9511748    0.1091543    0.6651190    0.9960394    .........
3 23    0.6825716    0.117533    0.8900186    0.9256916    0.9253819    0.6588873    .........
4 24    0.8280786    0.324110    0.6634117    0.7292685    0.0207334    0.9122315    .........
5 25    0.9520840    0.642721    0.5012283    0.2722650    0.2582217    0.3901019    .........
6 26    0.8714017    0.157062    0.8675581    0.5384571    0.6053657    0.5930488    .........
.  .        .
.  .        .
.  .        .
```

The dataframe has the first column to be the time variable `X`, and any other column with title `r_{i,j}` contains the time-varying correlations between the `i`-th and `j`-th variables.

Now, I am trying to make a matrix of plots of time-varying correlations for every pair of variables, using `ggplot2` or similar packages. This is probably not very difficult to do manually, but since I have `d` many variables, the process has to be automated. Essentially, my desired plot looks like the following:

|  |
| --- |
| [image: 2] |

Note that:

- For each plot, the X axis is the same, i.e., the variable `X` in the dataframe, with axis texts in the far bottom.
- The Y-scale in each plot should be same, i.e., 0 to 1.
- Lastly, there should be row and column names like 1,2,3,... in both the rows and columns.

---

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any clarification is neede. Thanks!

Comment: Would `ggpairs` from the `GGally` package help? [Documentation](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/reference/ggpairs.html)

Comment: This looks great. I'll have a detailed look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit different from a standard pairs plot, such as you might produce with `GGally::ggpairs`, since the x axis is constant across all plots.

If you want to build this yourself then you could automate using the patchwork package.

First, work out the row and column numbers that are going to appear in your plot, and what their names would be if they were columns in your data frame, *even for the blank spaces in your plot that do not have a corresponding column in your data frame*:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

n <- which(choose(seq(20), 2) == ncol(df) - 1)

pairs <- apply(expand.grid(seq(n-1) + 1, seq(n - 1)), 1, function(x) {
  paste0("r_{", x[2], ",", x[1], "}") })

pairs <- c(t(matrix(pairs, nrow = n - 1)))

pairs
#>  [1] "r_{1,2}" "r_{2,2}" "r_{3,2}" "r_{4,2}" "r_{1,3}" "r_{2,3}" "r_{3,3}"
#>  [8] "r_{4,3}" "r_{1,4}" "r_{2,4}" "r_{3,4}" "r_{4,4}" "r_{1,5}" "r_{2,5}"
#> [15] "r_{3,5}" "r_{4,5}"
```

Now we can create a plot for member of `pairs`. If it does not exist as a column in the data frame, we create an empty plot. If it is on the top row or the rightmost column, we add a single facet. If it is on the bottom or right, we use axis text, and remove it otherwise:

```r
plots <- lapply(pairs, function(i) {
  is_bottom <- grepl(paste0(",", n), i)
  is_right  <- grepl(paste0(n - 1, ","), i)
  is_left   <- grepl("1,", i)
  is_top    <- grepl(",2", i)
  is_col <- i %in% names(df)
  rowname <- sub("^r_\\{(\\d+),.*$", "\\1", i)
  colname <- sub("^.*,(\\d+).*$", "\\1", i)
  if(!is_col) {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(X, runif(length(x)))) + geom_blank()
  } else {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(X, .data[[i]])) +
         geom_line(linewidth = 1.5, color = "gray50", lineend = "round")
  }
  p <- p + scale_y_continuous(NULL, limits = c(0, 1)) +
           scale_x_continuous(NULL, 1:10) +
           theme_classic() 
  
  f <- quote(.~.)
  if(is_top) f[3] <- rowname
  if(is_right) f[2] <- colname
  if(is_top | is_right) p <- p + facet_grid(f)

  p + theme(axis.text.x = if(is_bottom) element_text()  else  element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = if(is_bottom) element_text()  else  element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = if(is_left) element_text()  else  element_blank(),
          panel.border = if(is_col) element_rect(fill = NA) else element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = if(is_col) element_line() else element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_blank())
})
```

To plot it, we can do:

```r
Reduce(`+`, plots) +
  plot_annotation(caption = "X", theme = theme(
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12)))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To plot a facet with the column name above each panel, change the creation of `plots` in the above code to:

```r
plots <- lapply(pairs, function(i) {
  is_bottom <- grepl(paste0(",", n), i)
  is_right  <- grepl(paste0(n - 1, ","), i)
  is_left   <- grepl("1,", i)
  is_top    <- grepl(",2", i)
  is_col <- i %in% names(df)
  if(!is_col) {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(X, runif(length(X)))) + geom_blank()
  } else {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(X, .data[[i]])) +
      geom_line(linewidth = 1.5, color = "gray50", lineend = "round")
  }
  p <- p + scale_y_continuous(NULL, limits = c(0, 1)) +
    scale_x_continuous(NULL, 1:10) +
    theme_classic() 
  
  f <- quote(.~.)
  f[3] <- i
  if(is_col) p <- p + facet_grid(f)
  
  p + theme(axis.text.x = if(is_bottom) element_text()  else  element_blank(),
            axis.title.x = if(is_bottom) element_text()  else  element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = if(is_left) element_text()  else  element_blank(),
            panel.border = if(is_col) element_rect(fill = NA) else element_blank(),
            axis.ticks = if(is_col) element_line() else element_blank(),
            axis.line = element_blank())
})
```

And when plotted, this produces

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- cbind(X = 1:10,
      replicate(10, sort(runif(10))) |>
      as.data.frame() |>
      setNames(combn(1:5, 2, FUN = \(x) paste0("r_{", x[1], ",", x[2], "}"))))

df
#>     X    r_{1,2}   r_{1,3}    r_{1,4}   r_{1,5}   r_{2,3}    r_{2,4}    r_{2,5}
#> 1   1 0.06178627 0.1765568 0.01339033 0.1079436 0.0233312 0.07067905 0.08424691
#> 2   2 0.20168193 0.2059746 0.12555510 0.1862176 0.4772301 0.09946616 0.25801678
#> 3   3 0.26550866 0.3800352 0.21214252 0.4112744 0.5297196 0.24479728 0.29360337
#> 4   4 0.37212390 0.3841037 0.26722067 0.4820801 0.5530363 0.31627171 0.33239467
#> 5   5 0.57285336 0.4976992 0.34034900 0.4935413 0.6470602 0.40683019 0.45906573
#> 6   6 0.62911404 0.6870228 0.38238796 0.5995658 0.6927316 0.43809711 0.47854525
#> 7   7 0.66079779 0.7176185 0.38611409 0.6684667 0.7323137 0.47761962 0.65087047
#> 8   8 0.89838968 0.7698414 0.65167377 0.7237109 0.7829328 0.51863426 0.76631067
#> 9   9 0.90820779 0.7774452 0.86969085 0.7942399 0.7893562 0.66200508 0.87532133
#> 10 10 0.94467527 0.9919061 0.93470523 0.8273733 0.8209463 0.86120948 0.91287592
#>      r_{3,4}   r_{3,5}    r_{4,5}
#> 1  0.3337749 0.1216919 0.05893438
#> 2  0.3390729 0.1433044 0.23962942
#> 3  0.3466835 0.2026923 0.41008408
#> 4  0.3899895 0.2454885 0.45527445
#> 5  0.4763512 0.3253522 0.60493329
#> 6  0.7773207 0.3999944 0.64228826
#> 7  0.8394404 0.4346595 0.77891468
#> 8  0.8643395 0.7111212 0.79730883
#> 9  0.8921983 0.7125147 0.81087024
#> 10 0.9606180 0.7570871 0.87626921
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Incredible! Thanks a lot. However, I have the following query: Is it possible to write the names of the pairs of variables on the top of every plot in a way exactly similar to what we see in case we use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`?

Comment: @JRC do you mean a strip at the top of each of the 10 panels, or four along the top and four along the bottom?

Comment: I was actually looking for the first kind that you mentioned. That is, a strip at the top of each of the 10 panels saying "r_{i,j}" for the plot lying in the intersection of the i-th row and j-th column. I'm not really sure how to do that. It'll be really helpful if you could help. Thanks!

Comment: @JRC ah! My bad luck to spend so long on the wrong guess. Anyway, it's a quick fix - see my edit

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. Thanks a lot for your time and efforts.